# delete all li except for previous five lis  and next five lis

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I want to delete all `li` within an `ul` except for previous five lis  and next five lis.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li id="Li0"></li>
    <li id="Li1"></li>
    <li id="Li2"></li>
    <li id="Li3"></li>
    <li id="Li4"></li>
    <li id="Li5"></li>
    <li id="Li6"></li>
    <li id="Li7"></li>
    <li id="Li8"></li>
    <li id="Li9"></li>
    <li id="Li10"></li>
    <li id="Li11"></li>
    <li id="Li12"></li>
    <li id="Li13"></li>
    <li id="Li14"></li>
    <li id="Li15"></li>
    <li id="Li16"></li>
    <li id="Li17"></li>
    <li id="Li18"></li>
    <li id="Li19"></li>
    <li id="Li20"></li>
</ul>
```

Let say I click on `Li` with `id Li9`. So the result should be

```
 <ul>
    <li id="Li4"></li>
    <li id="Li5"></li>
    <li id="Li6"></li>
    <li id="Li7"></li>
    <li id="Li8"></li>
    <li id="Li9"></li>
    <li id="Li10"></li>
    <li id="Li11"></li>
    <li id="Li12"></li>
    <li id="Li13"></li>
    <li id="Li14"></li>
</ul>
```

I know there are `:lt()` and `:gt()` selectors for excluding elements but till now I haven't made much progress.

Comment: Your example code doesn't reflect the thing you want made. You want to delete everything except the first and last five. But your example is the opposite. Please edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to remove all elements except the previous and following five, relative to the clicked element, you can use [`.slice()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) together with [`.index()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
// assuming `this` refers to the clicked li element
var index = $(this).index(),
    $lis = $(this).parent().children();

// Math.max(...) guarantees that we are not removing from 0 to the end of
// the list of `index - 5` is negative.
// Alternatively you can use `5 > index ? 0 : index - 5`
$lis.slice(0, Math.max(0, index - 5)).add($lis.slice(index + 6)).remove();
```

---

*This was the answer to the question "Remove all but the first and last five elements in a list".*

That's very easy to do with [`.slice()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('ul > li').slice(5, -5).remove();
```

Comment: This isn't quite right - he wants to remove the previous and next 5 `li` elements, relative to the one which was clicked.

Comment: @FelixKling I  have tried this but it is not working may be due to some syntax issue have a look. var ulPrnt = $(spnID).parents("ul:first");
    $(ulPrnt + ' > li').slice(5, -5).remove();

Comment: @ankur: To be honest, it's not 100% clear what you want to do. Do you want to remove all elements except for the first and last 5 in a list or do you want to keep the previous and following elements relative to the clicked one and remove all others?

Comment: @ankur: You should change the title as well and you should choose an example which is less ambiguous next time ;)

Comment: yes i will remember that. But there is small issue that needs to be addressed. which is if  the index(LI) you have clicked have less than five elements in previous or next to the clicked element everything is deleted.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the extended help . but it is not working properly .

Comment: @ankur: Then you have to explain better what you want to do, it works as I understood here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ctVA/

Comment: i will post the fiddle link in a moment .

Comment: @FelixKling what are you doing with this line $(this).parent().children().

Comment: @ankur: jQuery has extensive documentation: http://api.jquery.com/, which is worth a look. In short: It gets all the `li` element of the list, since `this` refers to `li` element, `$(this).parent()` returns its parent element (an `ul` element) and `.children()` gets all child elements a of node (which can only be `li` elements in case of an `ul` element). Maybe in your case, `this` does not refer to the `li` element but to some descendant. In that case you have to use the right methods (see the documentation) to get a reference to the `li` or `ul` element.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the elements relative to the one which was clicked on you need to use `index()`:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var $li = $('ul > li').slice($(this).index() - 5, $(this).index() + 6)
   $('ul > li').not($li).remove();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6JK/)

**UPDATE**

To account for scenarios where index+-5 is out of the bounds of the `li` index try this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var start = $(this).index() - 5;
    var end = $(this).index() + 6;
    var $li = $("ul > li");

    start = (start < 0) ? 0 : start;
    end = (end > $li.length) ? $li.length : end;

    var $keepLi = $li.slice(start, end)
    $li.not($keepLi).remove();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6JK/4/)

Comment: your script is working perfectly except few scenarios. If the index you have clicked have less than five elements in previous or next to the clicked element. So can you handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `:lt()` and `:gt()` selectors as you noted.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    index = $(this).index();
    $('ul > li:lt(' + (index - 5) + ')').
        add($('ul > li:gt(' + (index + 5) + ')')).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
```

});​

We select all the `li`s that have an index which is smaller than the clicked one minus 5, add to the collection all the `li`s that have an index greater than the clicked on plus 5, and then remove all those items.

Even shorter:

```
$('ul > li').remove(':lt(' + (index - 5) + '), :gt(' + (index + 5) + ')');
```

[`Remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) accepts an optional selector to filter elements in the current selection with.

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JJXFb/)